# Why did microsoft's developers choose to make the .NET a stack based machine?

Tags: .net, stack-based

Today I've found the Disassembler IL between the tools provided with VS2008. I tried to disassemble a program and give a look to the result. Opcodes weren't so hard to understand but one thing surprised me: the .NET is stack based?! Reading "Write great code, volume II" I didn't get a good picture of stack based machines because they're quite slow. They're easy to implement, too but I don't think MS devs chose this approach because of its simplicity, after all that code has to be translated into real machine code so they would just move the problem.
Can any of you explain this strange choice?

**PS**:
I post here what I read about this topic:

> **13.1.1 Stack-Based Machines**
>   Stack-based machines use memory for
>   most calculations, employing a stack
>   in memory to hold all operands and
>   results. Computer systems employing a
>   stack architecture offer some
>   important advantages over other
>   architectures:
>
> - The
>     instructions are often smaller (each
>     consuming fewer bytes) than those
>     found in other architectures because
>     the instructions generally don’t have
>     to specify any operands.
> - It
>     is generally easier to write compilers
>     for stack architectures than for other
>     machines because converting arithmetic
>     expressions to a sequence of stack
>     operations is very easy.
> - Temporary variables are rarely
>     needed in a stack architecture,
>     because the stack itself serves that
>     purpose.
>
> Unfortunately, stack
>   machines also suffer from some serious
>   disadvantages:
>
> - Almost every
>     instruction references memory (which
>     is slow on modern machines). Though
>     caches can help mitigate this problem,
>     memory performance is still a major
>     problem on stack machines.
> - Even though conversion from HLLs
>     to a stack machine is very easy, there
>     is less opportunity for optimization
>     than there is with other
>     architectures.
>
>   Because stack
>     machines are constantly accessing the
>     same data elements (that is, data on
>     the top of the stack), pipelining and
>     instruction parallelism is difficult
>     to achieve (see Write Great Code,
>     Volume 1 for details on pipelining and
>     instruction parallelism).
>
> A
>   stack is a data structure that allows
>   operations only on a few limited
>   elements of the stack (often called
>   the top of stack and next on stack).
>   With a stack you generally do one of
>   three things: push new data onto the
>   stack, pop data from the stack, or
>   operate on the data that is currently
>   sitting on the top of the stack (and
>   possibly the data immediately below
>   it).

and

> **13.1.1.5 Real-World Stack Machines**
>   A big advantage of the stack
>   architecture is that it is easy to
>   write a compiler for such a machine.
>   It’s also very easy to write an
>   emulator for a stack-based machine.
>   For these reasons, stack architectures
>   are popular in virtual machines (VMs)
>   such as the Java Virtual Machine and
>   the Microsoft Visual Basic p-code
>   interpreter. A few real-world
>   stack-based CPUs do exist, such as a
>   hardware implementation of the Java
>   VM; however, they are not very popular
>   because of the performance limitations
>   of memory access. Nonetheless,
>   understanding the basics of a stack
>   architecture is important because many
>   compilers translate HLL source code
>   into a stack-based form prior to
>   translating to actual machine code.
>   Indeed, in the worst case (though
>   rare), compilers are forced to emit
>   code that emulates a stack-based
>   machine when compiling complex
>   arithmetic expressions.

**EDIT:** I've just found [an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-have-a-stack) in @EricLippert's blog answering the question and confirming @Aaron's answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Keep in mind that just because the intermediate representation is stack-based it doesn't mean the generated machine code is stack-based.  As the code is converted from the intermediate form to machine code it's basically recompiled - allowing for local optimizations.

Once nice thing about using a stack-based intermediate representation is that you're not tied to any specific architecture.

Imagine if they had decided to use a theoretical register-based system as their intermediate form.  How many registers should they pick? 8?  16?  64?  If your target processor has more actual registers than the intermediate form then you've lost out on possible optimizations.  If your target has less actual registers than the intermediate then your optimizations are counter-productive because those registers are flushed to memory anyway.

Even on current CPUs you've got a big difference compiling down to x86 vs x64 - not to mention alternate architectures (ARM) or future architectures.

For something like this it's good that they kept it in the simplest form and then rely on optimization during final code generation to match it to the actual hardware.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, their first objective is portability?

Comment: @BlackBear - I'm not sure of their actual motives but certainly using a representation like this allows for being able to target and optimize for a wide variety of hardware.

Comment: Register based VM like the Lua-VM or Parrot have an infinite amount of (virtual) registers.

Comment: @helium not all register-based VMs are like that. For examle the Dalvik VM in Android has 16 or 65536 registers depending on the instruction

Answer (score 1):

The reason CIL is stack-based is because it was not designed to be an instruction set targeting a VM. It is an intermediate stage of compilation.

The CLR is more of a compiler+runtime rather than a VM like the JVM. The CLR design does not attempt to provide good performance of interpreted byte-code. Instead it attempts to check and compile a high-level byte-code to machine code at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to ask the Microsoft developers. But I would guess that the performance issue was not their #1 concern. Most Windows applications are not CPU-limited, or even really I/O limited, as they spend the great majority of their time waiting for for the user to click on a button. Having an architecture that allowed them to implement new languages easily probably was a priority, however.

Comment: but the xna is based on the .net and, about games, the faster the better

Comment: @BlackBear I doubt xna is very important to Microsoft, or to commercial games developers.

Comment: @BlackBear XNA is hardly the primary use case of the .NET framework.